# Are there any WebStorm plugins for documenting Angular projects?

Tags: angular, webstorm

Are there any plugins or tools for documenting classes and Angular libraries that use the intellisense?

Comment: Are you looking for a documentation library like [compodoc](https://compodoc.app/guides/getting-started.html)

Comment: like that, with intelli sense so I can use documentation in the ide too